# MySQL query joining table data

Tags: mysql

This is eluding me. I am trying to pull meta data about players that I have matched against each other in a game. Eg: Player 22 vs. Player 54

I have 2 mysql tables.

Table: players (id, name, image_url, etc)

1 | John | john.jpg | etc
2 | George | george.jpg | etc
3 | Ian | ian.jpg | etc
4 | Steve | steve.jpg | etc

Table: matchups (id, left_players_id, right_players_id)

1 | 1 | 3
2 | 2 | 4

I want to display the left player image and name and the right player image and name on my web page.

SELECT m.left_players_id, p.name AS left_player, m.right_players_id, p.name AS right_player
FROM players p, matchups m
WHERE m.left_players_id = p.id
AND m.right_players_id = p.id

0 results because of the AND (requiring a match that doesn't exist)

SELECT m.left_players_id, p.name AS left_player, m.right_players_id, p.name AS right_player
FROM players p, matchups m
WHERE m.left_players_id = p.id
OR m.right_players_id = p.id

4 results (dupes of each row)

What am I missing?

Comment: All amazingly quick and workable suggestions (I think). My next SO question I won't deviate so much from my real table names...I had a hard time converting these queries to match my actual setup. Ultimately, I got Rob's to work. Thanks to all three of you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to join to the players table twice, once for each player.

```
SELECT m.left_players_id, l.name AS left_player, m.right_players_id, r.name AS right_player 
FROM players r, payers l, matchups m 
WHERE m.left_players_id = l.id AND m.right_players_id = r.id
```

Comment: Thanks Rob. I got yours to work best with my table structure.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are referring to two different players at once, the Player table is needed twice, joined on the Matchups table to define the relation between left and right players.

```
SELECT l.name, l.image_url, r.name, r.image_url 
FROM Players l 
INNER JOIN matchups m ON l.id=m.left_players_id
INNER JOIN Players r ON r.id=m.right_players_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't select from multiple tables that way, you should use `INNER JOIN`, like this:

```
SELECT lp.name left_name, rp.name right_name
FROM matchups m
INNER JOIN players lp ON lp.id = m.left_players_id
INNER JOIN players rp ON rp.id = m.right_players_id;
```

That'll do the trick.